# .bat file to move files based on extension, spaces in filename

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, move

I've been trying to move some files into another folder, based on the file extension. Only problem is that the filenames have spaces in them.
In cmd prompt to move a single file I guess it would look like:

```
D:\move "D:\folder1\140227 file.xls" D:\folder2
```

In a bat file I've got:

```
for /R in D:\folder1 %%f (*.xls) do move %%f D:\folder2\
```

But obviously that doesn't work due to the lack of quotation marks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /R "D:\folder1" %%f in (*.xls) do move "%%f" "D:\folder2\"
```

..so put the quotes in...

(`in` keyword misplaced)

Comment: Then I get: "D:\folder1" was unexpected at this time